# Laravel: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'jon@doe.com' for key 'users_email_unique'

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have some trouble seeding actual data to my database. I get the error message:

```
"Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'jon@doe.de' for key 'users_email_unique'"
```

This is what my factory looks like:

```
$factory('App\User', [
    'name'     => 'Jon Doe',
    'email'    => 'jon@doe.com',
    'password' => password_hash('123456', PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
]);

$factory('App\User', [
    'name'     => 'Jane Doe',
    'email'    => 'jane@doe.com',
    'password' => password_hash('123456', PASSWORD_DEFAph ULT),
]);
```

I don't even run the UserTableSeeder, but it seems to fire the jon@doe.com again.

Any clues?

Here is my DatabaseSeeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        // $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
        $this->call('ClientTableSeeder');
        $this->call('OrderTableSeeder');
        $this->call('FileTableSeeder');
    }

}
```

And this is my UserTableSeeder, which is commented out above

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

// composer require laracasts/testdummy
use Laracasts\TestDummy\Factory as TestDummy;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        TestDummy::times(1)->create('App\User');
    }

}
```

Please advice.

Comment: You code looks a little off. The given code has doe.com while the error is about doe.de.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is an obvious one, just use faker to generate your dummy data in your factory

```
$factory('App\User', [
'name'     => $faker->name,
'email'    => $faker->email,
'password' => password_hash('123456', PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
```

]);

because you have the duplicated email addresses and you have set a unique rules in your migration

in case you would like to override the dummy data, you can do

```
$overwrite = ['name' => 'Jon Doe','email' =>'jondoe.email.com'];
TestDummy::times(1)->create('App\User',$overwrite);
```

Comment: Thx for the comment, but this couldn't help me, because the error that I get, is due to "duplicate" email addresses. My migration requires that emails ought to be unique. Nonetheless this does not address the problem either, since my initial problem ist that for every created order a new user was created, which was weird enough... thanks for responding anyway.